# Satellite L640 Battery Applet Problem

Tags: 12.04, battery, applet, toshiba-satellite

Hayy guy i got a satellite l640 and i installed ubuntu 12.04 on it and i dont get the battery percentage ive tried a fair bit but this is my first time using linux.

Ive gone into the power option and ive installed battery status apps and still i get nothing.
There was one saying how much amps and what not the battery has and it all has 0.00 for everything, ive also tried the terminal cammands to see the percentage and that doesnt work.
Is there anything i can do or should i just got back to windows.

Answer (score 1):

Just passed by this post while searching for a similar issue with fan on my Toshiba Satellite L650.

If your problem has not been solved you can try this. This works on my machine perfectly.

Download these two files and place **01_acpi** in `/etc/grub.d/` and `chmod +x` it with root privileges. Then place **dsdt.aml** in `/boot` and run `update-grub2` in terminal.

After rebooting the machine, the battery applet should work fine.

Here are the links to the files.

[**01_acpi**](http://ubuntuone.com/2SPv45bwKdshHtt67ruSDx)
[**dsdt.aml**](http://ubuntuone.com/0FVRN3ELEAKuelFz68xXYC)

Comment: I re-read your post and somewhere it looks like that you'll feel some problems in performing the tasks. here is a little more help about it.
While copying the files to respective directories you'll need the root privileges, you can easily escalate to root by typing in a terminal **gksu nautilus**. This will ask for root password and then open a window with root privileges. after copying the files to respective directories run these commands in terminal:

`sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/01_acpi`

`sudo update-grub2`

And reboot your system.

Answer (score 0):

I'v provided the exact command above, if you have placed the file at `/etc/grub.d/01_acpi` then just copy and paste this command in terminal

`sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/01_acpi`

You may also use *Nautilus* to do the same, just fire up a terminal and type `gksu nautilus`, enter password when prompted and Nautilus window will appear. Go to `File system > etc > grub.d` find the file `01_acpi` Right click on it and go to `properties > permission` and check the box `Allow executing file as program`
Thats all!